# How to create filter for "Discover" tool in Kibana with conditions?

Tags: if-statement, elasticsearch, filter, kibana

I need to create a filter for the "Discover" tool in Kibana that filters requests only inside a particular app.

For example, I have the following apps: Config, Device.
In each Config request, I have a message with a string that defines a country. For example: "country=№1", "country=№2", "country=№3.
So I use a filter **"message:"*country=№2*""**. This filter excludes not only requests with "country=№1" and "country=№2" strings but also all the requests from the "Device" app.

The "message="*country=№2*" filter has the following code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "*country=№2*",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently I also use **"app:"Config""** filter which has the following code:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "app": "Config"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

How can I combine this code in one filter so I could filter requests for **"country=№2"** but only inside the "Config" app and still receiving requests from the "Device" app? I need particular requests from both apps.

Comment: Have you tried adding [filters on various fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html)?

Comment: Yes. I can exclude unwanted countries but the question still stands, because I can use the same technique in other places with the same problem. I need to specify a particular kubernetes.container.name and I can't exclude others because there are too many of them and what is more important I don't know their names.

Comment: And also requests for the "Device" app exclude requests from the "Config" app. So I have to apply the solution in multiple places and excluding hardly helps.